# Why can't '\b\w+(?=ing)\b' match "I'm singing while you're dancing"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex

```
var reg = /\b\w+(?=ing)\b/g;
var str = "I'm singing while you're dancing";
str.match(reg) // ==>null
```

But if the regex is `/\b\w+(?=ing\b)/g` then the str can match 'sing,danc'

Why does that mach but my previous example doesn't?

Comment: Don't overcomplicate your regex: `/\b\w+ing\b/g`.

Comment: he doesn't want to match the ing part

Comment: @marvel308 He is in javascript we could extract capturing groups.  A more serious concern is that he does not want to match 'sing,danc', so \b is the wrong thing to test for.  - But without a clear description of why the match on 'sing,danc' is false finding the correct character group is impossible.

Comment: he never said he doesn't want to match sing and danc, he wants to know why the 2nd regex matched and the first one did not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the \b at the end since the part you want to match does not end on a boundary . danc and sing would batch \b\w+\b but dancing and singing would not

```
\b\w+(?=ing)
```

check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/1eXhjR/1)

```
\b\w+(?=ing\b)
```

would make sure that your ing is at the boundary and not the

```
\w+
```

part

Comment: `\b\w+(?=ing\b)` was rejected in question.  OP does not want to match 'sing,danc'.

Comment: he didn't reject it, he wanted to know an explanation of why it matched sing and danc and the above regex did not

Answer (score 4):

Because the `(?=ing)` is a zero length match.  So you are trying to match one or more word characters followed by 'ing' that at the same time is followed by a word boundary.

Because a word boundary is a change from word characters to non-word characters, a word character followed by an 'i' is not followed by a word boundary.

`/\b\w+(?=ing\b)/g` matches the 's' in 'sing,danc' because ',' is a non-word characater - and therfore there is a word boundary between the 'g' and ','.  To find the correct regexp you need to be clearer on why 'sing,danc' should not match.

Comment: thank you,and may i ask you another regexp question,can you tell me '/((^|%>)[^\t]*)'/g' match what...I don't know '(^|%>)' means what,I test many times,but the results are not what I expect!

Comment: No need to bother you,I have alreay know why,thank you~~

Comment: @Perhaps There are utilities online that allow that aids regexp writing.  for example typing `(^|%>)` into https://regex101.com/ explains that it's a capturing group with two alternatives; either match start of string, or match '%>' literally.